# Some Images not loading on iOS device/emulator Ionic v1 but works fine in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ionic-framework

The following HTML tag works fine on an ionic modal to load an image.
 `<img src="img/bandeiras-iugu.png" alt="Visa, Master, Diners, Amex, Elo" border="0" class="pl-center" />`.

The problem is that when I try to use a string to bind as HTML in a popup button,  the image doesn't load, just the span tags`'<span class="pms"></span><img src="img/ic_motorcycle_black_24dp.png" height="40px"><br><span class="pms">Delivery</span><br>'`.

I used the console.log to log the buttons array of the popup and this is the result:
`[{"text":"<span class=\"pms\"></span><img src=\"img/ic_motorcycle_black_24dp.png\" height=\"40px\"><br><span class=\"pms\">Delivery</span><br>"}]`.

I have noticed that if I remove the style directive from this tag, the image will load fine.
`<img src="img\Security-Approved-icon.png" alt="Secure" border="0" style="height:2em" class="pl-center" />`

This code used to works fine with no problem, but now I need to release a new version and this problem has appeared. I don't if this has to do with Crosswalk plugin. I deleted it because it wasn't needed anymore. This problem is only on iOS. On Android and Browser there's no problems.

Can someone help me? I'm really lost at this problem because I didn't find anything over the internet.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you try converting the string to html in a safe way?

Comment: like sanitize ? ionic popup already use ng-bind-html. I think it should convert it in a safe way. Anyway. I Would appreciate anything that can help in solving the problem. Can you send anything about converting string to html ?

Comment: What about the img src that works and the other that only works without the style directive? Do you know anything ?